# Compatibility problems during migrating database from SQL 2005 Standard to SQL 2008 R2 Web Edtition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-migration

we have some troubles with migrating user database from SQL 2005 Standard to SQL 2008 R2 Web Edtition. After selecting .bak file containing backup, the Management Studio spits out error saying:

```
Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)
```

(More details at: http://pastebin.com/u1cZP25S)

Trying to restore from query with VERIFY ONLY option results in:

```
Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Read on "E:\XXXMigration\XXX.bak" failed: 38(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The problem is that's the last DB from this server which has to be migrated. Other 5 databases were migrated (back-up & restore) without any problem.

I know there is issue with migrating from 2005 Enterprise to 2008 Express (from higher to lower edition) and that you cannot migrate from higher version to lower (from 2008 to 2005 and so on ...).

But as I figured out, the web edition of SQL 2008 R2 should be in fact the Standard edition with some minor limitations. And I don't know, why this specific database cannot be restored on Web Edition and what causes this. Could be there some particular features / settings used in database which prevents it from restoring on target server?

```
Database server info:

Source database server: 9.00.1406.00    RTM    Standard Edition
Target database server: 10.50.1600.1    RTM    Web Edition (64-bit)
```

Thank you for any advice.

**EDIT**

I've found out that restoring this database to 2008 R2 Enterprise is possible and then when I backup it there, it's possible to restore it on 2008 R2 Web Edition. Not a nice workaround, but saves the situation.

Still curious why this situation can occur.

-- M. Frank (miroslav.frank (at) e-fractal.cz)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the Upgrade Advisor http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11455 - it might be able to highlight problems for upgrading the original database.

Also, have you looked into the compatibility level of the database, ensuring that it is being imported as a 2005-database? This has worked for me with several databases, although in situations that did not also include different editions of the server.